# How to get the price of Friday close in pinescript

Tags: datetime, pine-script

I'm trying to store the Friday close price with this code:

```
study("My Script")
endOfDay = 1600 //session end, in exchange local time, in 24hours format: 9:30AM=930, 4pm=1600
lastBarOfDay = (hour(time_close)*60 + minute(time_close)==(60*(endOfDay/100)+endOfDay%100))?1:0

friclose=0.0

friclose := dayofweek == 6 and lastBarOfDay? security(syminfo.tickerid, "D",close)  : friclose[1]
plot(friclose)
```

it works for the daily timeframe, however if I switch to any intraday timeframe the closing price is incorrect, I can't figure out why this happens?

or would anyone know of a better way of getting the weekly friday close, and only updating it after the current friday close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
closingHour = input(16)
closingMinute = input(00)

sessionCloseTime = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, closingHour, closingMinute)

bool isLastBarOfWeek = false

if timeframe.isintraday and dayofweek == dayofweek.friday
    lastBarTime = sessionCloseTime - timeframe.multiplier * 60000
    isLastBarOfWeek := time >= lastBarTime

float FridayClose = na
if barstate.isconfirmed and isLastBarOfWeek
    FridayClose := close
else
    FridayClose := FridayClose[1]
    
plot(FridayClose)
```

Comment: thank you very much this works for intraday.